# How to get an object of key-value pairs where the value will have only projected fields in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

In Mongodb how to I project only the required fields into an embedded object in mongodb, where the key will be an value of a selected field from the same document and also group them based on similar value of a field
If you look at the result am expecting below, the `car_id` that's same has to be grouped and the value has to be the key-value pairs of `ObjectId` and only the selected fields I want i.e `accessories`.
Let's assume I want to match using `brand` that has `honda`
Below is the documents I have in a collection called **CARS**

```
{
_id : '1'
car_id : 'A'
brand : 'honda'
accessories : [{parts:6, name:'speaker'},{parts:2, name:'headlight'}] 
},
{
_id : '2'
car_id : 'A'
brand : 'honda'
accessories : [{parts:6, name:'speaker'},{parts:2, name:'headlight'}] 
},
{
_id : '3'
car_id : 'B'
brand : 'honda'
accessories : [{parts:6, name:'speaker'},{parts:2, name:'headlight'}] 
}
{
_id : '4'
car_id : 'C'
brand : 'honda'
accessories : [{parts:6, name:'speaker'},{parts:2, name:'headlight'}] 
}
```

Below is the result I am expecting

```
{
 'A' : {
          '1': {accessories : [{parts:6, name:'speaker'},{parts:2, name:'headlight'}]}
          '2': {accessories : [{parts:6, name:'speaker'},{parts:2, name:'headlight'}]}
       },

'B' : {
          '3': {accessories : [{parts:6, name:'speaker'},{parts:2, name:'headlight'}]}
       },
'C' : {
          '4': {accessories : [{parts:6, name:'speaker'},{parts:2, name:'headlight'}]}
       },
}
```

[image: Am getting this below error]

The second result am expecting

```
{
 'A' : {
          '1': {
                _id : '1'
                car_id : 'A'
                brand : 'honda'
                accessories : [{parts:6, name:'speaker'},{parts:2, 
                name:'headlight'}] 
               }]}
          '2': {
                 _id : '2'
                 car_id : 'A'
                 brand : 'honda'
                 accessories : [{parts:6, name:'speaker'},{parts:2, 
                 name:'headlight'}]
               },

'B' : {
          '3': {
                 _id : '3'
                 car_id : 'B'
                 brand : 'honda'
                 accessories : [{parts:6, name:'speaker'},{parts:2, 
                 name:'headlight'}] 
               }
       },
'C' : {
          '4': {
                 _id : '4'
                 car_id : 'C'
                 brand : 'honda'
                 accessories : [{parts:6, name:'speaker'},{parts:2, 
                 name:'headlight'}] 
               }
       },
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `$group` - Group by `car_id`. Set the `cars` array field with the document containing the `k` (`_id`) and `v` (`accessories` array) fields.
2. `$group` - Group by `null` in order to make all documents into one. Set the `data` array field with the document `k` (`car_id`) and `v` (key-value pair from `cars`) array.
3. `$replaceRoot` - Replace the input document with the new document by converting the `data` array into a key-value pair.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$car_id",
      cars: {
        $push: {
          k: "$_id",
          v: {
            accessories: "$accessories"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      data: {
        $push: {
          k: "$_id",
          v: {
            $arrayToObject: "$cars"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        $arrayToObject: "$data"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/l3lvePyvGjx)

Comment: am getting this error which I have attached in my description above, `_id` is an ObjectId

Comment: Your actual data doesn't match with the data you provided in the question. As the error stated, the `k` must be a string, you can use `$toString` operator to convert ObjectId to string. Example: `k: { $toObjectId: "$_id" }`

Comment: It worked thanks, but also is there a way to return the whole object as a value for an _id in the embedded object?

Comment: Would be great if you can share your expected output for better clarification.

Comment: Yes, I have edited my description you can find it under `The second result am expecting`

Comment: Seems this is the [demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/f9MPNZswiCu) that you want?